# How to update view data on android when change in MySql server?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

I am develop my android application with Java and Restful API's. The API's server has used MySQL server.
I faced a problem that is, when I change on my server, The view can't updated as per as firebase realtime database. It's work when I go back and open the activity again, or I used onResume method and declare here the code for fetch data.

How can I do it automatically?
Thank you for Advanced.

Comment: Hi, probably you are attempting some sort of polling? You can send send push notification to the app about the changes, use WebSocket connection or update some sort of field in the firebase, in this way the app will be notified about the changes and call specific backend url to fetch the results. It really depends on your structure and what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

I would personally make it so where the code that changes the data in the database, it also sends a message to the client (I'd have a websocket open for this) saying that there is an update, on receiving this they can re-fetch the api.

You could also make it so that the server sends the updated data but there is a chance what the user sees and the true data desync.

You could also just have the client re-fetch the api every x seconds depending on how often you expect changes to be made but this option really depends on your ccu and resources.